# Is a Locale considered complete only if

Tags: java, locale, currency

Example: In the class `Currency` there is a static method `getInstance(Locale locale)`.
However If I write something like:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("it"));
```

It gives an exception (IllegalArgument..)

On the other hand:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("it-IT"));
```

Compiles without problem.

Can we safely say that without the country code the locale it's incomplete?

Note that specifying the only language it's a valid option to construct a Locale in some circumstances es:

```
Locale localize = Locale.forLanguageTag("it");
    System.out.println(localize.getDisplayName());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a Locale that represents just a language without a country, that's perfectly valid.

But you cannot get a currency from a language, since currencies are related to countries, not languages. The country of Italy does have currency, the Italian language does not...

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc for Currency#getInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) explains:

> Returns the Currency instance for the country of the given locale. The language and variant components of the locale are ignored

And if you check the [Locale#forLanguageTag javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a locale for the specified IETF BCP 47 language tag string.

If finally you refer to [how those tags work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag#Syntax_of_language_tags), you will see that "it" is Italian and "it_IT" is Italian_Italy.